# Refactor program for multithreaded HTTP client requests

Tags: go, google-places-api

I'm reading the docs for the Google Places wrapper, but it only supports Google Nearby Search. This isn't really a huge bottleneck.

My script does a Nearby Search to find the Place_ID's of that area, then proceeds to do a Places Details query to get all of the data from that specific Google Maps business entry.

This Places Details query is where the bottleneck is, and I was hoping I could get some feedback on this script I wrote.

It appears it is NOT multi-threaded, but when I increase 'threadcount' from 1 to 40, my sample script run time drops from 40s to 12s.

I had to do a lot of copy and pastin, and trial and error, to get this functioning. I really appreciate the help here.

1. Why is this running faster when I increase the threadcount to 40?
2. How can I speed this up even faster with multithreading?

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "log"
    "crypto/tls"
    "googlemaps.github.io/maps"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
)

var threadCount = 40
var wg sync.WaitGroup

var api_key = "api_key"
var top_cities_gps = "./top_cities_gps"
var next_page_token = ""
var business_types = []string{"accounting", "art_gallery"}

var connector = &http.Transport{
    MaxIdleConns:       threadCount,
ring('\n')
      if err != nil {

          log.Fatalf("read file line error: %v", err)
          return
      }

      _ = line

            // alright! let's kick this up a notch, and start scraping!!! :D
            // looping all business types

            for i, s := range business_types {

                // now let's hit Google Places API for a NearbySearch!
                // 
                searchPlaces("", s, strings.TrimSpace(line))

        }
  }
}

func main() {
    GoGoogle()
}
```

Comment: You probably want to be setting `MaxIdleConnsPerHost`, which by default is only 2.

Comment: You're also not using the `go` keyword anywhere in this code, so I'm not sure how you expect to increase the concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

`threadCount` is misnamed. It is only used to set the `MaxIdleConns` in HTTP transport. According to docs:

```
 // MaxIdleConns controls the maximum number of idle (keep-alive)
 // connections across all hosts. Zero means no limit.
```

So when you increase `threadCount` from 1 to 40, you increased the limit for keep-alive connections. From this usage, it appears that setting `threadCount` to 0 would give you the best result.

I suggest you get rid of `threadCount` completely.